# Circular progress bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, uiprogressbar

I want to implement some circular progressbar with a button at the middle like in whatsapp. Does anyone know of a good library to accomplish that? What I want to accomplish is this.
[image]

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. The Android Arsenal has [many, many progress indicators](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/76), some of which may meet your needs.

Comment: this is easy to use and customize: https://github.com/natasam/DemoProgressViewsLibApp

Comment: https://github.com/Adilhusen/circle-progress-ad-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to create a custom progress bar.

I would recommend this tutorial: http://mrigaen.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/create-circular-progress-bar-in-android.html

However, there are probably other perfectly good ones out there as well.
The one I have linked will provide you with the actual progress bar. You will then be able to add a simple button to your layout in in the center of the progress bar.